# How to write 'x said they would do y but...' in predicate logic?

Tags: semantics, logic

How do I write "X said to Y that they would do A today, but B happened yesterday" in predicate logic?

So for example;
Bart said to Lisa that he would braid her hair today, but he chopped his hand off yesterday'

**Edit for possible answer:**
I have come up with two possible answers, although both may be completely off track...

BRAID(bart, lisa, hair) ∧ CHOP(bart, hand)

SAID(bart(BRAID(bart, lisa, hair)) ∧ CHOP(bart, hand)

**Edit for context**: my question just states 'predicate logic notation'. We have never called or been taught it under any other name, but some of my textbooks use the term 'first order logic'
The sort of things we have covered so far are:

- • L: is a linguist  • R: reads  • S: is a semanticist  • c: Chomsky 
  • g: Gosia

*Translate*

1. ∀x(S(x)→L(x))
2. ∃x(L(x)∧R(x,c))
3. Gosia is not a linguist but she reads Chomsky anyway

Comment: By which, do you mean "any order predicate logic"?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'any order' predicate logic is, I'm afraid. I believe I mean first order predicate logic- although none of my textbooks seem to make a distinction.

Comment: There are many ways of expressing it, you should give us some context or framework.

Comment: Edited to add more information, but I'm not sure there is much context I can give

Comment: Does the generalized form "(X said (Q at time x)) and (B at time y)" lose too much of the intended message? For example, is "but" crucial for your purpose, or would "and" do as well. Are you allowed three-place predicates?

Comment: We are allowed three place predicates. We've been taught that there is not a connector for 'but' and it is represented by 'and' (which is one of the main problems of predicate logic). My issue is whether I need to actually put the 'said' in, or whether it's ignored

Comment: Your “possible answer” isn’t first order. In first order logic you’d need to reify the embedded clause (as described, for example, in Parsons’ “Events in the semantics of English”).

Answer (score 1):

> *Bart said to Lisa that he would braid her hair today, but he chopped his hand off yesterday.*

(SAY (BART,
               (INTEND (BART,
                                           (TODAY (BRAID (BART, LISA_HAIR))))) 
                                      
                                          LISA))
               ∧
(YESTERDAY (CHOP_OFF (BART, BART_HAND)))

Using the convention of Source, Trajector, and Goal, in that order, for 3-place SAY puts *LISA* at the end. That doesn't matter for [predicate calculus](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), since dative is syntax, not semantics. Also tense doesn't matter, so SAY is fine, and I've represented *Lisa's hair* and *Bart's hand* as single objects so as to avoid unnecessary lambdafication.

Note that there is nothing contradictory here; the implications of Bart's missing hand yesterday and its results on his braiding Lisa's hair today are not part of the logic, but rather the contextual interpretation. It's signalled by the *but* in the sentence, but it has no place in the logic; that's why *but* = *and* in logic.

Comment: This isn’t first order.

Comment: Why are logical connectives called “functors” in the PDF? In formal logic a functor is typically the first part of a predicate’s signature.

Comment: What exactly is it then please, Atamari?

Comment: @Eloisa Higher-order logic. In FOL only individuals can be arguments of predicates and functions.

Comment: Nonsense. Any well-formed formula can be an argument of any predicate. This formula isn't even quantified, unless you want to get very technical about _today_ and _yesterday_; and it's certainly first-order, since it doesn't quantify over predicates.